# When I set a cookie in the controller, why can't Poltergeist read it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, capybara, poltergeist

I want to test that a controller sets a cookie. I have a controller

```
# app/controllers/home_controller.rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    cookies[:foo] = "bar"
    head :ok
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: "home#index"
end
```

When I write a test

```
require "capybara/poltergeist"

class CookieTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Capybara::DSL

  setup do
    Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist
  end

  test "cookies" do
    visit "/"
    page.driver.cookies #=> {}
  end
end
```

The cookies are blank, even though `HomeController` set a cookie. Why is that? When I visit the same page with my browser, then the cookie is indeed set (I ran `document.cookie` in the JavaScript console).

Comment: Do you need to wait for the request to complete?

Comment: Capybara code (depending on the driver) can be asynchronous - just because the driver method returns doesn't always mean that all the associated stuff has completed. May or may not be the case for visit, but all it takes to find out is a quick call to sleep

Comment: The only thing that can be asynchronous is the JavaScript. Every Capybara driver always returns after an action has been finished. One weird thing is when I put `Capybara.app = MyApp::Application`, then the above example works. However, it still doesn't work in my main application (this is just an isolated example).

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I forgot to put in the test_helper.rb

```
Capybara.app = MyApp::Application
```

In the real example in my application I was actually using Cucumber with RSpec, not MiniTest. I was testing GitHub authentication. And the problem was that I was redirecting to `http://example.com`, instead of my app. Cookies are set per domain, so when I entered `http://example.com`, my app's cookies are no longer present.